# Saving the contents to a file and then reading it back and displaying it

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, save

I have some details which is an Image on Canvas, XAML in textbox and items in listbox. How do save all these contents in one single file regardless of the extension. I should also be able to open these files and put back all the contents back to their place which is Image in Canvas, XAML in textbox and items in listbox. I tried to save the details in String and save it but I cant open it again and put back the contents.

The code which I am using to save the contents is:

```
String Data = imagesource + xamldata + xamldesign + listboxitems;
try
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    file.WriteLine(Data);
    file.Close();
}
```

Here imagesource is the source from where the image is got. xamldata is from the textbox and listboxitems has the list of items present in listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, nope.
 Things are little bit more complex here. You should understand and accept a new paradigm called "serialization" - all these things in your list: image, text, items in listbox have different nature and purpose, they can easily be stored in the same file but should be:
1. distinguished
2. properly treated - i.e. you take image as a series of bytes, put it in some place in file (defined by length, or by data structure itself), then on loading you take it back from file, recreate image, place it on canvas, same thing for text, and elements.

Computer just cant read your mind and understand which bytes go where. It's up to you to "teach" it how parts of information you stored are treated right. Usually for such task class is created, something like :

```
 public class StoreClass {
   public byte[] Image {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public List<MyListItem> ListContent {get;set;}
 }

//here goes MyListItem definition
public class MyListItem {....}
```

then you fill this class when needed and serialize it on disk, later you load it from disk (process called "desirialization") and place its content in right places.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)